# How do I assign a column in a csv file by python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I have a CSV that I want to graph.

However, to get this graph, I need to first assign a column to a list (or array) and then go on from there. I need to assign the first column to said list. In the said column, there are many repeats of the numbers 1 through 45 (so in code that would be `range(1,46)`).

Currently, I have written this so far:

```
for weekly sales against Date 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    %matplotlib inline

a = []

for stn in range(1,46):
    a.append(walmart[walmart.Store == stn])

for printval in range(1,46):
    b = a[printval-1]
```

**NOTE:** `walmart` (the value associated to the dataset) has already been read here by `pd.read_csv`. It works and an output has been made.

I do not know what to do from here. I want to graph this as well based on the store.

The data set can be found: https://www.kaggle.com/divyajeetthakur/walmart-sales-prediction

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what I need to do to get this to work. The following code describes my situation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

a = []

for stn in range(1,46):
    a.append(walmart[walmart.Store == stn])

for printval in range(1,46):
    b = a[printval-1]
    w = b[b.Store == printval]
    ws = w["Weekly_Sales"]
    tp = w["Date"]
    plt.scatter(tp, ws)
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Weekly Sales')
    plt.title('Store_' + str(printval))
    plt.savefig('Store_'+ str(printval) + '.png')   #To save the file if needed
    plt.show()
```

Again, I have already imported the CSV file, and associated it to `walmart`. There was no error when doing that.

Again, the dataset can be found in https://www.kaggle.com/divyajeetthakur/walmart-sales-prediction.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but the easiest that comes to mind is using [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

First you need to install it in your environment. I see you tagged `anaconda` so this would be something like:

```
$ conda install pandas
```

Then import them in your python file (presumingly Jupyter notebook)

```
import pandas as pd
```

Then you would import the csv into a dataframe using the build in [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function (*you can do many cool things with it so checkout the docs*)

In your case assume you want to import just columns say number 3 and 5 and then plot them. If the first row in your csv contains the header (say `'col3'`and `'col5'`) this should be read automatically  and stored as the column name(If you want to skip the header reading add the option `skiprows=1`, if you want the columns to be named something else use the option `names=['newname3', 'newname5']`

```
data = pd.read_csv('path/to/my.csv', usecols=[3,5], names=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Then you can access the columns by name and plot them using `data['colname']`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.scatter(data['col1'], data['col2'])
plt.show()
```

Or you can use the [built in function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) of pandas dataframes:

```
data.plot.scatter(x='col1', y='col2)
```